# getElementById is not working in opera 12.15

Tags: javascript, dom, element, opera, getelementbyid

I am using javascript on client-side in my app, I need to get the element based on the id, class and tagname, I am using following code for getting element using `id`.

```
     HTML:
          <!Doctype>
          <html>
          <head>
          <script>
           (function (tag,fp,n) {
             var d = document;
             a = d.createElement(tag), m = d.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
             a.async = 1;
             a.src = fp;
             m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })('script', 'cs.js', 'cs');
          </script>

         </head>
         <body>

           <div id="id">click me</div>
          </body>
          </html>


  javascript(cs.js):

 ;(function(w, d) {
       var util  = {
      getElements : function(selector) {

        var result = [];
        var hashIndex = selector.indexOf("#");
        var dotIndex = selector.indexOf(".");

        if(hashIndex > -1){
            selector = selector.substring(hashIndex+1);
            var domElem = d.getElementById(selector);
            console.log(domElem);
            if(domElem !=null){
                result.push(domElem);
            }
        }
        else if(dotIndex > -1){
            selector = selector.substring(dotIndex+1);
            var domElem =  d.getElementsByClassName(selector);
            if(domElem !=null){
                result = domElem;
            }

        }else{
            var domElem = d.getElementsByTagName(selector);
            if(domElem !=null){
                result = domElem;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
  };

  console.log(util.getElements("#id"));


})(window, document);
```

It works correctly in chrome, firefox but in opera it gives `null`.

`Browser Info:` Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15

Any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Can you share a live example of the problem? Meanwhile, [this bin](http://jsbin.com/ufomam/1/edit) works perfectly fine on Opera 12.15 for W7.

Comment: Try constructing a *complete* reduced test case. We can't tell what is wrong from that snippit. (And having the value of the id being `id` suggests that even that snippit is contrived and might not reflect the code that isn't working).

Comment: FabrícioMatté's code also works fine on Opera 12.15 for OS X.

Comment: @user2281294: What do you think that will do internally? jQuery is in no way preferable to `getElementById`

Comment: @Bergi, i have a doubt, is there any difference between $(".classname") & document.getelementsByClassName("classname")?

Comment: @karthick.k, now you have added your code to the question, also consider creating a jsfiddle for it so that others can see the problem first hand (if they have that browser on the same/similar platform)

Comment: @Xotic750 javascript is loaded `async` how to make jsfiddle demo

Comment: Alternatively, provide a link to your working page (non-working Opera) if you don't have the time to figure out jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<script>` element appears before the `<div>` element you are trying to select.

Using `async` doesn't guarantee that the DOM Ready event will fire before the script runs.

Move the script so it appears later in the document, or bind it to an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try giving the domElement a name via "name"-attribute and do:

```
var domElement = document.getElementsByName("element_name")[0];
console.log(domElement);
```

I hope it works that way.

Comment: Please don't answer such vague questions. `getElementsByName` is in no way preferable to `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that version of Opera to test your claim but you could consider [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) as an alternative.

HTML

```
<div id="id"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var domElement = document.querySelector("#id");
console.log(domElement);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/zVSd8/)

Update for @bergi

Here is an example where the environment has been broken, this may be intentional in design (who knows), anyway the OP has not control over said environment.

```
document.getElementById = function () {
    return null;
};

var domElement = document.getElementById("id");
console.log(domElement);

domElement = document.querySelector("#id");
console.log(domElement);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/9KMhQ/)

Oh dear, `getElementById` does not work, but `querySelector` does.

I am not disagreeing that the question is vague, but still ...

Comment: Please don't answer such vague questions. `querySelector` is in no way preferable to `getElementById` (there's one specific case, but you had to mention that)

Comment: I didn't say "prefereable" but "consider as  an alternative", and this would be such a specific case if getElementById is not working. But please tell me what you had in mind?

Comment: No. If `document.getElementById` isn't working (returning `null`), `querySelector` will not be working either.

Comment: Consider that the user environment may be broken in some way, and he has no control over this. See my update

Comment: Uh, that's a pretty bad excuse.

Comment: You gave me little or nothing to work with, "No", just like the OP, but your sweeping statement is actually worse I think, as it was proven not true "If document.getElementById isn't working (returning null), querySelector will not be working either." Using an alternative had some merit as it could be used towards a diagnosis.